# How to iterate over a formbuilder in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I try to iterate over a form control but get some problem. I use the FormBuilder from Angular2.

I have following code in my controller:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let data = this.dataSet[this.key];
    this.form = this._fb.group({});

    Object.keys(data).forEach(name => {
      this.form.addControl(name, new FormControl());
      this.form.controls[name].setValue(data[name]);
    });

    console.log(this.form);
  }
```

That gives the following output on the console:

```
FormGroup
  ...
  controls: Object
    database1: FormControl
      ...
      _value: Object
      accessHost: "some host here"
      accessKey: "the key here"
....
    database2: FormControl
      ...
      _value: Object
      accessHost: "some host here"
      accessKey: "the key here"
```

That looks OK for so far. 
the html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSave(form)">
  <div *ngFor="let ups of form.controls | keyVal; let i=index">
  {{ups.key}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="{{ups.key}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But this part is not working:

```
<input class="form-control" formControlName="{{ups.key}}">
```

When I check the value of {{ups.key}}, that is "database1". Is "database1" in this case not a FormControlName?

Thanks for Help

Comment: Look at this [Cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the formControlName attribute to an expression:

```
<input class="form-control" [formControlName]="ups.key" />
```

Notice the [] arround the attribute.
A good start is to take a look at this cookbook: [Dynamic Form](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html) as suggested by @kcp

Comment: Thanks for that hint, I know this cookbook. They talk about dynamic Form.
i changed to expression and get "[object Object]" in the field.

Comment: That's because the value is a complex object. Look at your console output the _value is Object.

Comment: I know, thats a misunderstanding. I will put the control "database1" to input not the _values. "database1" is FormControl not an Object.